# Why can I not rename columns of a tbl?

Tags: r, dplyr

I came across a weird function in `dplyr`'s tbl:

```
df <- as.tibble(iris)
i <- colnames(df)[5]

df$new <- df[,i]
```

For some reason the newly created column new is named `new.Species` (at least when I `View(df)`), however it should be named `new` only....

I do not understand why this happens. An obious fix is to simply save df as a data.frame - but I still would like to understand what happens here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `df[,i]` is still a tibble with one column.  We need `df[[i]]`:

```
df$new <- df[[i]]
```

---

With `data.frame`, when we use `[`, by default `drop = TRUE` (`?Extract`), but in `tibble`, it won't drop the dimensions to create a vector.  We need `[[` to extract the column.